# AsyncTask Implementation using callback interface - Handle multiple call responses in single callback interface

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my Android application, I am making multiple API calls from one Activity. I am using following approach: Implementing interface in Activity and call that interface function from Async class.

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    public void processFinish(JSONObject sb);
}


public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject> {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    String url;
    String method;
    String payload = null;
    AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    public FetchData(AsyncResponse delegate, String url, String method) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
    }

    public FetchData(AsyncResponse delegate, String url, String method, JSONObject payload) {
        this(delegate, url, method);
        this.payload = payload.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(this.url);

            // Open HTTP connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // HTTP method GET/POST/PUT/DELETE
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod(this.method); 

            // handle issues
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            // Get the response
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            if(inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String inputLine = null;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine + "\n");
            }

            return new JSONObject(response.toString());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            try {
                // Return error response
            } catch(Exception e1) {
                System.out.println(e1);
                return null;
            }
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        this.delegate.processFinish(result);
    }
}


public class AsyncTasks extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse {
    TextView view = null;
    int a = 1;
    Utility utility = Utility.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_async_tasks);
        new FetchData(this, "<url 1>", "GET").executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

        new FetchData(this, "<url 2>", "GET").executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(JSONObject data) {
        utility.showDialog(this, data.toString());
    }
}
```

Here how to handle response of 2nd GET call in **processFinish()** interface function? What is the best approach?

Comment: if both the url's are different then simply adding condition to match with the provided url and read the response.

Comment: There might be chances of having same URL's. Is there any way to identify the call by setting tags or etc ? Please provide sample code.

Comment: I would add some request id to constructor of your FetchData and pass it back in processFinish to distinguish both requests.

Comment: yeah, you have to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    //Add requestCode to identify request.  
    public void processFinish(JSONObject sb, int requestCode);
}


public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject> {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    String url;
    String method;
    String payload = null;
    AsyncResponse delegate = null;
    int requestCode;

    public FetchData(String url, String method) {
        this(url, method, null);
    }

    public FetchData(String url, String method, JSONObject payload) {
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
        if(payload!=null){
             this.payload = payload.toString();
        }
    }

    //You can set AsyncResponse and RequestCode in constructor also.
    public FetchData setListener(AsyncResponse asyncResponse, int requestCode){
        this.delegate = asyncResponse;
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(delegate!=null){        
            //post result with given requestCode
            this.delegate.processFinish(result, requestCode);
        }
    }
}


public class AsyncTasks extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_async_tasks);

        // Make first call with request code as 1    
        new FetchData("<url 1>", "GET").setListener(this, 1).executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

        // Make second call with request code as 2
        new FetchData("<url 2>", "GET").setListener(this, 2).executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(JSONObject data, int requestCode) {
        switch(requestCode){
            case 1:
            //perform task on 1st call finish
            break;
            case 2:
            utility.showDialog(this, data.toString());
            //perform task on 2nd call finish
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe i'm a bit late.
But i was facing the same problem as you and this switch case in the validated answer was burning my eyes so here you can find a way of implementing it for as many requests as you want using anonymous AsyncResponse.

In you fetch data when you are passing your AsyncTasks class to manage the callBack by implementing the processFinish Method, change it with a new AsyncResponse and implement in the method.

Like This:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    //Add requestCode to identify request.  
    public void processFinish(JSONObject sb, int requestCode);
}


public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject> {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    String url;
    String method;
    String payload = null;
    AsyncResponse delegate = null;
    int requestCode;

public FetchData(String url, String method) {
    this(url, method, null);
}

public FetchData(String url, String method, JSONObject payload) {
    this.url = url;
    this.method = method;
    if(payload!=null){
         this.payload = payload.toString();
    }
}

//You can set AsyncResponse and RequestCode in constructor also.
public FetchData setListener(AsyncResponse asyncResponse, int requestCode){
    this.delegate = asyncResponse;
    this.requestCode = requestCode;
    return this;
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    ....
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(delegate!=null){        
            //post result with given requestCode
            this.delegate.processFinish(result, requestCode);
        }
    }
}


public class AsyncTasks extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_async_tasks);

    // Make first call with request code as 1. Use anonym callBack implementation
    new FetchData("<url 1>", "GET").setListener(new AsyncResponse () {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(JSONObject sb, int requestCode) {
                //perform task on 1st call finish
            }
        }, 1).executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

    // Make second call with request code as 2
    new FetchData("<url 2>", "GET").setListener(new AsyncResponse () {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(JSONObject sb, int requestCode) {
                //perform task on 2st call finish
            }
        }, 2).executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

    // Make as many call to FetchData and implement an anonym AsyncResponse each time

}
```